# JFrame close issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have Main class, StartFrame extends JFrame, and UserPanel extends JPanel which I add to StartFrame. I have button in the UserPanel, how can I close StartFrame when I press the button(I am familiar with event handling it's not a problem the issue is how to sent info to the StartFrame) . Or it is better to just change the panel of the frame(size if need) and reuse it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to close a window that is enclosing a component, you need a reference to that Window, and SwingUtilities has a method that can help you get this: `getWindowAncestor(Component c)`. Then you could call `dispose()` on the window returned.

i.e.,

```
Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(myJPanel); 
win.dispose();
```

Note that this is fine if you're using this to end your GUI, but if your goal is to swap views, then a better suggestion is not to swap Windows, but rather to leave the main JFrame visible but to instead swap components it shows with a CardLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The button is already on the frame (on the upper right, here).  Just call `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` when constructing it and it will work as the user expects.

#### Other tip

Don't extend frame or panel, but instead just create and use them.

Comment: I am saying about another button , which I add by myself.